# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion

Tags: android, json, url

This code works fine in leapdroid, but I get error emulator :

> 2020-06-25 13:43:36.936 14930-14930/? E/databaselesson: Unknown bits
> set in runtime_flags: 0x8000 2020-06-25 13:43:54.808
> 14930-14998/com.webstates.databaselesson2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: Thread-5
> Process: com.webstates.databaselesson2, PID: 14930
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
> at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
> at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
> at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.webstates.databaselesson2-4k_62xOXrMgiDzbzDcYzKw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.webstates.databaselesson2-4k_62xOXrMgiDzbzDcYzKw==/lib/x86,
> /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109) 
> at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97) 
> at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)

My code is:

```
package com.webstates.databaselesson2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    String url="https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";
    ArrayList<Item_Data> arrayList;
    ListView listView;
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ReadObjects();
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Read_From_Url();
            }
        });
        //



    }

    private void Read_From_Url() {


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error "+error.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);



/*
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error "+error.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        Mysingletone.getSingle(getApplicationContext()).add_to_Req(jsonArrayRequest);
*/
    }

    private void ReadObjects() {
        listView=findViewById(R.id.activity_main_listview);
        bt1=findViewById(R.id.activity_main_bt1);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<Item_Data>();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Android don't have the support for Apache HTTP client. To solve this, in your Manifest file, insert the following inside `<application>` tag:

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```

Further information about why Google made this change is [available here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p).